# Unable to load the requested class: cartthrob_loader

Tags: cartthrob

Want to checkout as a guest. No login.

On EE 5 and Cartthrob 4.2.

When I send the checkout_form I get this error

```
Unable to load the requested class: cartthrob_loader
```

What might cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed with version 4.3.